# Border of UITextField in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios8.1

When user click on `UITextfield` its border highlight like native application of mac. Shown blue `UIColor` like animating. I am new in iOS. Please help . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried...

Comment: This site is not to learn basic. Search on internet, Learn How do to, And try your self And when you face problem in your try than ask here and show what you have tried. Just 5 sec of google give me this : https://coderwall.com/p/hsrecw/add-a-border-to-any-uiview

Comment: Check my answer. you can change textfield border color with animation.

Answer (score 1):

Use layer property of `UITextField` to make a border around it.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:151.0/255.0f green:193.0/255.0f blue:252.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
textField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0f;
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

Change `borderWidth` and `cornerRadius` value for more accurate and desire value as like mac application textfields.

Answer (score 1):

In your TextField delegate method : Put below code.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{
    _txtF.layer.borderColor= [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    _txtF.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    _txtF.alpha = 0.0;

    //somewhere here should be the [someView addSubview:tmp];
    //and after that should go the [someView addSubview:yourTextFieldView];

    //somewhere later in your code, when you need the animation to happen
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{

        UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:_txtF.bounds];
        _txtF.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        _txtF.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        _txtF.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
        _txtF.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
        _txtF.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
        _txtF.alpha = 1.0;
        _txtF.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    }];
}
```

Your OUTPUT is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to implement uitextfield delegate

1.

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == yourtextField) {
        yourTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    }
}
```

2.

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == yourtextField) {
        yourTextField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
        yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    }
}
```

If you don't know about delegate then study about delegates in ios and afterwards use this code

Hope it will help you